# Multiple query using Sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i have the following code in Java and SQLite (Android) and something is not working.

```
public void copybydateandreg(String FromDate, String ToDate, String reg) throws SQLException{

        /* YYYY/MM/DD */


           Log.v("copiez", "Functie!");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Temp ("
                + "Total_Flight_Time,"
                + "Operational_Condition_Time_Night, "
                + "Operational_Condition_Time_Instrumental, "
                + "Single_Pilot_Time_SE, "
                + "Single_Pilot_Time_ME, "
                + "Multi_Pilot_Time, "
                + "Pilot_Function_Time_PIC, "
                + "Pilot_Function_Time_COPILOT, "
                + "Pilot_Function_Time_DUAL, "
                + "Pilot_Function_Time_INSTRUCTOR, "
                + "Aircraft_Registration, "
                + "Simulator_Training_Session_Duration) "

                + "select "

                + "Total_Flight_Time, "
                + "Operational_Condition_Time_Night, "
                + "Operational_Condition_Time_Instrumental, "
                + "Single_Pilot_Time_SE, "
                + "Single_Pilot_Time_ME, "
                + "Multi_Pilot_Time, "
                + "Pilot_Function_Time_PIC, "
                + "Pilot_Function_Time_COPILOT, "
                + "Pilot_Function_Time_DUAL, "
                + "Pilot_Function_Time_INSTRUCTOR, "
                + "Aircraft_Registration, "
                + "Simulator_Training_Session_Duration  "


            + "FROM Flights WHERE Flights.Date >= date('"+FromDate+" 00:00:00') AND Flights.Date <= date('"+ToDate+" 23:59:59') AND Flights.Aircraft_Registration LIKE '"+reg+"'");
```

and i call the function with 2 dates and "YR-5321" for `reg`. The problem is that is is not copying data.
I tryed to copy only using date filtering and it worked but when i add the reg part it is not working.

DateTo - Date
DateFrom - Date
Reg - String

Comment: Why do you compare with LIKE without wildcards? Which content is in `Aircraft_Registration`?

Comment: 'VARCHAR'
Also cand you explain me how wildcards are working or what they are?
Thanks.

Comment: Please give examples of the content of this column. Is it 'YR-5321' or is it 'Flight YR-5321 (JFC->MUC)'. It's important because the way you use `LIKE` you could as well use `=`.

Comment: So try the query with = instead of LIKE

Comment: The same problem, no data in Temp. Also, i have data to copy from Flights so ...

Comment: Seems like you don't have any rows for your selection criteria. I assume you don't get any exceptions from SQLite.

Comment: No exception, but i do have rows with that Aircraft_Registration :|

Comment: Last comment by me: install app on emulator or rooted device; `adb shell`; `cd /data/data/your-package-name/databases`. `sqlite3 your-db-name.db` and then play with your SQL.

Comment: I created a code to export the db to external memory this is how i know that the table is empty :)

EDIT: i will create an other table and i will try to copy to TEMP from Flights only by date and then copying from TEMP to TEMPO by Aircraft Registration, that should work too :))

Thanks for your interest :D